# Put csv contents into a muti dimension array

Tags: php, csv, multidimensional-array

I have a csv files that contains the following lines

```
enter code here

23,cars,43 063
23,cars,17 306
23,houses,13 300
23,garage,13 094
23,hotels,10 025
22,cars,75 675
22,cars,40 403
22,houses,32 243
22,garage,30 649
22,hotels,29 734
21,hotels,29 734
22,hotels,29 734
```

And here is the code that i am using to parse the csv file

```
     function readCSV($csvFile){
$file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
}



fclose($file_handle);
return $line_of_text;




    }
```

When i display the contents of the $line_of_text; array, here is what i get

```
      Array
       (
      [0] => Array
      (
        [0] => ï»¿23
        [1] => cars
        [2] => 43 063
      )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 23
        [1] => cars
        [2] => 17 306
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 23
        [1] => houses
        [2] => 13 300
    )
```

.....

But this is not what i want, i would like my array to be displayed in this way

```
 array (
 23 => array(
    'cars' => 43063,
    'houses' => 17306,
    'shops' => 13300,
    'garages' => 13094,
    'hotels' => 10025
 ),
 22 => array(
    'cars' => 75675,
    'houses' => 40403,
    'shops' => 32243,
    'garages' => 30649,
    'hotels' => 29734,
    'test' => 29734
     )
    );
```

How do i acheive this ? Can  you please help me ?

//UPDATES  contents of new my array

```
 Array
 (
 [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => cars
        [1] => 00
        [2] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => cars
        [1] => 01
        [2] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => cars
        [1] => 02
        [2] => 0
    )


[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => cars
        [1] => 11
        [2] => 0
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => cars
        [1] => 23
        [2] => 4425
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => houses
        [1] => 00
        [2] => 198
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => houses
        [1] => 01
        [2] => 742
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [0] => houses
        [1] => 02
        [2] => 168
    )
)
```

Comment: You could easily rebuild the data the way you'd like it by looping through and building a new array, or by building the array as you go via the original loop & the value of fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);

Comment: @skrilled, do you have an example of this ?, I am very to new php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$fp = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
$master = array();
while( $line = fgetcsv( $fp ) ) {
    // 23,cars,43 063
    if( !isset( $master[$line[0]] ) )
        $master[$line[0]] = array();

    if( !isset( $master[$line[0]][$line[1]] ) )
        $master[$line[0]][$line[1]] = 0;

    $n = filter_var($line[2], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $master[$line[0]][$line[1]] += $n;
}

var_dump( $master );
```

Didn't test, but should work.  Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: @Saeven, how can allow the array to accept duplicate values ? when my array is arranged in this way ? i have edited my original question

Comment: Should probably leave this question as is, and then start a new thread for your new question.  Improves the quality of SO as a knowledgebase. Feel free to message me with your new question thread.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this!

```
$line_of_text=array();
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);

    if(isset($line_of_text[ $line[0] ][ $line[1] ] ))
        $line_of_text[$line[0]][$line[1]]+=str_replace(" ", "", $line[2]);
    else
        $line_of_text[$line[0]][$line[1]]=str_replace(" ", "", $line[2]);

}
```

Comment: I have tried to insert the data into a new csv file using @Saeven code but i am getting a new line for each key in the array. This is what i get when i insert the data in a csv file                23,17306
23,13300
22,13094
22,10025                                                              i would like to have one line for each key and the values seperated by a ","                                                               For example                                              23,17306,13300
22,13094,10025                                                       HoW do i a acheive this?